# Standard machine Startup folder Excel 2019

Tags: excel, startup, add-in

Where is the standard machine startup folder for Excel 2019 (I need to place my xla files there).

in Excel 2010 (32bit): `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\XLSTART`
in Excel 2016 (32Bit): `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\XLSTART`
in Excel 2019 (32Bit): ???

Answer (score 1):

in Excel 2019 (32Bit): `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\XLSTART>`

maybe this also works for Office365 installations.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have [step-by-step instructions](https://medium.com/lets-excel/ms-excel-tip-easily-locate-your-startup-and-add-ins-folders-ec853b105dcd) to obtain the path you are looking for in any version of Excel.

Comment: Thank you,  I already tried this methods, but these are not the standard (machine) paths I am looking for. As you can see in my examples for 2010 and 2016

Comment: Quite to the contrary. These are indeed standard paths. They are installed with the installation by the installation and for the installation. Therefore the installation knows where they are. If you want to make headway, please advise the path that Excel gives you in response to `Debug.Print Application.StartupPath` and why it isn't the path you are looking for.

Comment: the Output you are asking for is `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART` 
But this is not what I am searching for.
Meanwhile I found the standard machine path: 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\XLSTART>` 

I do not know why, but putting files in this folder, adds XLA and XLAM to the startup, as expected (because in the previous version, that was the way it worked for me.

Comment: Regarding you comment: "standard"  -> YES you are correct. I know this method. "standard machine" -> NO, that is what I was looking for.  With the "standard machine path" we can deploy XLA(M) files for the entire company, without getting inconsistencies.

Comment: Excel has a default path for add-ins. Using the startup path instead seems complicated. Usually that path is at  `C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\.` but there should be a way to get the path from the machine if you have different systems.

Comment: Having hundreds of User, the easiest way for me is to put the file in one fixed Folder. I cannot see why this should be"complicated". Maybe this is because I do not understand how to deploy such file in another way (as you might be considering). Sorry for that.

Comment: MS thought exactly the same. So they created a fixed folder to keep add-ins. Your argument is that it isn't a "fixed" folder because it can be in different locations in different versions. But that also applies to the STARTUP folder. Therefore your problem shifts to finding out whether it's easier to find the STARTUP or the Add-in folder. If you can find code that gives you the correct path on every system, like `Environ("UserProfile")`, you wouldn't care about the name of the folder. Else, Add-ins can be in any folder. Create your own dedicated folder that is really fixed where you create it.